# right-hand-side MySQL functions in DBIx::Class

Tags: mysql, perl, dbix-class

In DBIx::Class, when I generate a query using this syntax:

```
...
'Time(submitted_at)' => { '>' => 'Time(Now()-Interval ' . $wait_period . ' minute)' }
...
```

The generated query is perfect except for the fact that the function on the right hand side is in quotes.

```
... AND ( Time(submitted_at) > 'Time(Now()-Interval 5 minute)' ) ...
```

If it was not quoted then it would be correct.  How would I do that?

Thanks,
Rob

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Pass the string as a scalar reference instead:

```
...
'Time(submitted_at)' => \"> Time(Now()-Interval $wait_period minute)" 
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  I can't seem to figure out though why it is not interpreting references in that way though.  With the above (not changed at all) I get this SQL generated:

... ( Time(submitted_at) > 'SCALAR(0x108b8cd8)' ) ...

Comment: Hmm, I guess it only likes scalar refs at the top level of the hash.  I've modified my answer accordingly, does it work now?

Comment: Yup I figured that out just now and was about the post it, but you beat me to it.  Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6):

It [seems](http://search.cpan.org/~ribasushi/SQL-Abstract-1.60/lib/SQL/Abstract.pm#WHERE_CLAUSES) that the way to do expressions is to pass a scalar ref or array ref if you want to use literal SQL.

Here's an example showing using a query parameter for the `$wait_period` variable into the expression:

```
...
'Time(submitted_at)' => { '>' => \['Time(Now()-Interval ? Minute)', $wait_period] }
...
```

Comment: +1 for using a query parameter rather than plain string concatenation